# Incrementing 0.1 in floating point number 0.0 gives unexpected result in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, while-loop, floating-point, increment

I was writing a code to print the sequence 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, ......,1.0 in **Dart**.
I used **while** loop and wrote the following code

```
void main() {
  var i = 0.0;
  while (i <= 1) {
    print(i);
    i += 0.1;
  }
}
```

now the compiler is giving me an unexpected result of my code

```
0.1
0.2
0.30000000000000004
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.7999999999999999
0.8999999999999999
0.9999999999999999
```

Can anyone tell what exactly is happening

Comment: Relevant: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Suppose you changed your increment step to `i += 1./3;`.  Since 1/3 = 0.333333 is an infinitely-repeating decimal fraction, you would not be surprised if you saw a few anomalies like this.  Well, it turns out that, in the binary systems that computers typically use, 1/10 is an infinitely-repeating fraction, too.  In decimal it's 0.1 exactly, but in binary it's `0.00011001100110011…` .

Answer (score -1):

If you need to print this toStringAsPrecision can fix this
If you need it to be double again try `double.parse(i.toStringAsPrecision(2));`

```
void main() {
  var i = 0.0;
  while (i <= 1) {
    print(i.toStringAsPrecision(2));
    i += 0.1;
  }
}
```